# JQuery SlideDown and SlideUp within nested DIV tags

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I'm working on a menu system that works with two different organizational structures:

A. to hover over one group title and have all the content appropriate to that group slideDown.

B. to hover over a category that applies to only some of the content in more than one group and have all of the contents within this category slideDown, regardless of what group they are in.

The first part works like this...example...

http://jsfiddle.net/nWJhH/

The second part is posing some problems...

http://jsfiddle.net/GBkMB/12/

My intention is to hover over 'breakfast' for example, and have 'milk, apple, and lettuce' slide down even though they are in different groups. Then when you mouse out of the 'breakfast' title everything below will slide up into their originial groups. But for some reason I can't seem to get the slideDown to apply.

Any ideas? Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick if you want only the elements applicaple to the cat needs to be displayed, also removed the repeating code

```
$('.content').hide();
var $elms = $('.fruit, .vegetable, .dairy');
$elms.hover(function() {
var $content = $(this).children('.content');
    $content.stop(1,1).slideToggle(600);
});
var items=['breakfast','lunch','dinner'];

$(items).each(function(){
   var sel=this;
   $('#'+sel).hover(function() {
      $('.'+sel).parent().slideDown(400);
      $('.'+sel).siblings(':not(.'+sel+')').hide();
      $(this).addClass("black");},
    function(){
      $('.'+sel).parent().slideUp(400);
      $('.'+sel).siblings(':not(.'+sel+')').show();
      $(this).removeClass("black")
   });
});
```

If you want the entire block containing item then just remove the sibling toggle part

http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/GBkMB/29/

Comment: I have updated your fiddle code also here [http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/GBkMB/29/](http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/GBkMB/29/)

Comment: This is great! The only thing is that the animation will run through EVERYTHING  in order that the mouse has passed over instead of stopping an animation that was accidentally moused over to play ONLY the one the mouse is currently on... does this make sense? I can tell it has something to do with 'content.stop' logic but I'm having a hard time understanding how I can appl;y that

Comment: you can add a delay by using hoverintent plugin here http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html its very simple

Comment: When I played with it more, I realized it doesn't always work the way it should. THings are not displayed correctly if you hover over things in a certain odrder. The use of show/hide also makes it jump around instead of running smoothly. See what I mean? I'm going to try toying with it more later.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the parent of your items(content) is hidden so the items are sliding and all but because their parent is hidden they wont show. :)

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/nheJ9/

its not really tidy and I changed some classes etc but thats because I thought it made more sense.

The point is you can see that when the parent is enabled they will show ^.^